# Adding a TeamCity build step for dotTrace with thresholds for all unit tests

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, resharper, performance-testing, jetbrains-ide

I would like to add performance thresholds for all unit tests in my build step using the `dotTrace` plugin for `TeamCity`. Referencing the article [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/02/16/performance-profiling-in-continuous-integration-an-updated-dottrace-plugin-to-teamcity/), the example seems to indicate that you have to put individual threshold values for each method.

Specifically I'd like to know the following,

1. Is there a way to have the build just compare a previously generated performance profile **on all unit tests** against a new one (without having to specify threshold values for each individual method).
2. Can this also be accomplished using the `ReSharper Ultimate` plugin with `dotTrace` for `Microsoft Visual Studio`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that this was not possible, according to the comment by Alexey Totin [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/02/16/performance-profiling-in-continuous-integration-an-updated-dottrace-plugin-to-teamcity/#comment-460072) (as of March 22, 2016).